# Archlinux mount: /new_root: unknown filesystem type 'ext4'

Tags: arch-linux

I updated my system using `yaourt -Syua` and there was an update for the Linux kernel. 
I tried rebooting and got:

`loading linux linux...`
`loading ramdisk...`
Then crash and redirection to the emergency shell, like described in the link below:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=237303

I use UEFI and grub.

I can't type anything in the emergency shell because my keyboard doesn't work.

I tried using a bootable archlinux on USB drive but failed with

> SQUASHFS: xz decompression failed, data probably corrupt

Details about my hard drive : I have a dual boot Linux/Windows with some system partitions.

Is there a way to fix my system without losing data?

Comment: Try use fallback initramfs. If that doesn't work, try Remake a live USB(see ArchWiki), chroot into your system. use pacman to update your kernel again. I guess You have interrupted your system update process.

Comment: Well my bootable USB stopped working. I'm burning the 2019/01/01 iso from my Windows.